# Missing JSON values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an html table that is being populated with a json file. When you click on a row, if the row has a sub row (a child row) those child rows will be displayed when the row is clicked on (initially the child rows are hidden).

As I mentioned I have a json file but for this example I'll use a javascript array:

```
   var data = [
 {    

     "ID" : 2,
     "FirstName" : "John",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "Test",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNodeId":0
    },

     {
     "ID" : 3,
     "FirstName" : "Test",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "Test",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNodeId":2
    },

     {
     "ID" : 4,
     "FirstName" : "Helen",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNodeId":0
    }

];
```

The 2 elements being compared here are "ID" and "HeadNodeId". If "HeadNodeId" has the same number as "ID", then that is a child of that row. I have JavaScript code to do this but only one parent row and its child rows are being displayed, not the other rows that don't have child rows:

So this is working:

```
{ 
  "ID" : 2,
 "FirstName" : "John",
 "LastName" : "Test",
 "DOB": "Test",
 "Gender":"M",
 "HeadNode":0
},

 {
 "ID" : 3,
 "FirstName" : "Test",
 "LastName" : "Test",
 "DOB": "Test",
 "Gender":"M",
 "HeadNode":2
},

 {
 "ID" : 3,
 "FirstName" : "Test",
 "LastName" : "Test",
 "DOB": "Test",
 "Gender":"M",
 "HeadNode":2
},

 {
 "ID" : 3,
 "FirstName" : "Test",
 "LastName" : "Test",
 "DOB": "Test",
 "Gender":"M",
 "HeadNode":2
}
```

Parent row and its child rows are working, but these aren't being displayed at all. These are not child rows, so they should always be shown:

```
{
     "ID" : 4,
     "FirstName" : "Helen",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":0
    },

    {
     "ID" : 5,
     "FirstName" : "Helen",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":0
    }
```

It seems like my outer for loop is just iterating once. Here is the code snippet for this:

```
var i=0;
var k=0;
function populate(){

    var data = [
 {    

     "ID" : 2,
     "FirstName" : "John",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "Test",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":0
    },

     {
     "ID" : 3,
     "FirstName" : "Test",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "Test",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":2
    },

     {
     "ID" : 3,
     "FirstName" : "Test",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "Test",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":2
    },

     {
     "ID" : 3,
     "FirstName" : "Test",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "Test",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":2
    },

     {
     "ID" : 4,
     "FirstName" : "Helen",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":0
    },

    {
     "ID" : 5,
     "FirstName" : "Helen",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M",
     "HeadNode":0
    }

];

  var tr, td;
  var tbody = document.getElementById("data");

    // loop through data source
    for (i; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].ID == data[k].HeadNode){break;}

        tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = data[i].ID;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i].FirstName;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i].LastName;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i].DOB;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i].Gender;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i].HeadNode;



      for (k; k < data.length; k++) {
         if(data[i].ID == data[k].HeadNode){
        tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        tr.className = "subnode";
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = data[k].ID;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[k].FirstName;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[k].LastName;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[k].DOB;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[k].Gender;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[k].HeadNode;
       }
    }
   } 
}
```

I feel like this is part of the problem:

```
if(data[i].ID == data[k].HeadNode){break;}
```

How can I fix this using pure JavaScript (no libraries)? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are your loops nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it goes like this:

```
for i {
    if data[I].HeadNodeId !== 0) continue;
    // Render "parent"
    for k
        if (data[k].HeadNodeId !== data[I].Id) {
        // Render child
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your entire methodology. Here's what I recommend.

```
var doc = document;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function C(e){
  return doc.createElement(e);
}
var tbody = E('data'), ord = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'DOB', 'Gender']; // Object Literals make their own order
for(var i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++){
  var o = data[i], tr = C('tr');
  for(var n=0,q=ord.length; n<q; n++){
    var td = C('td');
    td.innerHTML = o[ord[n]]; tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.